# Unable to connect on Browser Node JS Application

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

I just Created a sample test file for my new server (*hostgater* **VPN SERVER**) to test the node js Application ? I am shocked when I saw its running at the back end from the terminal but when I access from the browser its showing ***"Unable to Connect"*** .

I have Centos Server 6.7 final

The Steps I followed

1. Install the node js From the official site documentation from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/).
2. Check the node version and npm version ? Everything ok, its showing

> node - v
>       4.4.4
>       npm -v
>       2.15.1

3. Create a sample file name Server.js

**Server.js**

```
  var http = require('http');
  http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
  }).listen(3000);
  console.log('Server running at 3000/')
```

4. Run the file with node command node **server.js**.

Its Running Successfully and console the message also but when I start listen the app at the browser ***xyz.com:3000***. Its Showing Unable to connect.

I can't understand what I am missing, Can anyone guide me.

Comment: Is your server's firewall blocking the port by any chance? Are you accessing it through the right IP/hostname?

Comment: yes i am accessing it thriug the ip or host name both? Same issue

Comment: Your code works fine on my machine. It must be a port being blocked.

Comment: Yes it also works fine in my local machine but when i try on the server its Showing this Kind of Error? This happens First time With me.

Comment: Any idea How can i resolve it

Comment: You say 'when i try on the server', that implies you have an external machine to run your script (and I just read your question again, you have a VPS running at Hostgater). Is the port 3000 forwarded to that machine in that network and once again, is the port blocked by the firewall?

Answer (score 1):

Contact your server hosting provider (Hostgater) and make them forward port 3000 to your server.

Another solution could be using port 80 instead of 3000, as that port is most probably already open and forwarded.

Comment: i agree with your answer but i had already two more servers ? In that there is no problems of ports ? I can use any port or any number? any solution for that

Comment: Yes, you can use any port you want aslong as its not in use, its not blocked by a firewall and its forwarded. The other servers, if they run on a different hostname/IP, have nothing to do with it. What you could try is start this script on your remote server in a screen or a separate SSH instance and run 'curl localhost:3000' from the same server. Does it show you 'Hello World'? Then your app runs fine but its just not accessible outside the machine/network.

Comment: yeah its show `hello world` in the terminal itself ? Now what to do? Can i contact with my service provider

Comment: That means your app is running fine but access to your server on that port is blocked by, once again, a firewall or the port is not forwarded. Contact your service provider.

Comment: Yeah i already give you points?? and let me solve my issue i ll accept your answer thnx?

Comment: Thanks? The problems is in the port? that is Blocked.? Now its Working

Answer (score 1):

Please add some route in it for browser or add

```
http.get({
  hostname: 'localhost',
  port: 80,
  path: '/',
  agent: false  // create a new agent just for this one request
}, (res) => {
           res.setHeader();
           res.send('Hello World');
           res.end();
  // Do stuff with response
})
```

Comment: there is no problem in route? Even i don't want the Routes? I just Simply testing? The problem is in the iptables.? Thanks i ll give u the credit for you trying to help me.